# Scale functionality for apps on iOS tablets

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

I'm developing an app with Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio and I'm aware of a function on iOS tablets where you can scale up apps that are formatted for smartphone use.

Is it possible to implement this feature for use on tablet devices, and could it be implemented on Android as well?

I included a screenshot of the PayPal app on an iPad, which makes use of this function for a better understanding, the marked button does the scale-magic.

[PayPal app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeoNO.jpg)

Comment: this is a feature of iOS itself, not of Xamarin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is not something that you can influence as a developer. An iPad user is able to find iPhone apps from the store and can choose to install it anyway.

Whenever a user does, it comes with default, built-in functionality in iOS that lets them zoom the app for a bit.